# SSIS DB2 to SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, ssis, db2, odbc, oledb

I'm trying to establish a connection between our SQL Server 2017 instance and an ISeries AS400 (IBM) database for data integration.

When i use and OLE DB source in my data flow tasks, the connection succeeds, but the execution is pretty slow. The team that manages AS400 told us that, using a JDBC or ODBC provider we should have better performance while reading data.

I did setup the ODBC connection to AS400 in VSDT Connection Managers, attached it to a ODBC Source component and, if i press "Preview" on the data source task configuration, i see that the connection correctly opens and data is shown.

But, if i run the entire task, it always fails stating that:

> "[ODBC Source [11]] Error: The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager AS400iseries failed with error code 0xC0014009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.
>   "

What am I doing wrong? Isn't the preview a sufficient method to verify that connections work?

P.S. The data flow task is just a 1-to-1 copy of data into SQL Server, with the add of a fixed-value column. The task works perfectly using OLE DB driver and data source.

EDIT: already tried with forcing 32-bit debug configuration and nothing changed.

I'm using iSeries Access ODBC Driver 32-bit (v13.00.01.00), also tried with 64 but with no result

Comment: You've hit the primary impediments (matching driver bit'edness with SSIS execution mode). It's terribly curious that the preview works but the run doesn't. Could there be a user/password issue that only presents itself at run time? What is your package protection level set at?

Comment: At the moment, also the run is working. For me a fix was to create both ODBC data source registrations for the same AS400 server, but one made with 32-bit tool and the other with the 64-bit. SAME NAME. So, now, the preview executes using the 32-bit driver (because of the fact that VSDT is a 32-bit piece of software) and when i run it in a job, for example, SSIS targets the same data source, but the 64-bit version. I know this can be a work-around but for me it works and it does not seem to be a bad solution. Is there something else i should consider in your opinion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, also the run is working. For me a fix was to create both ODBC data source registrations for the same AS400 server, but one made with 32-bit tool and the other with the 64-bit. SAME NAME. So, now, the preview executes using the 32-bit driver (because of the fact that VSDT is a 32-bit piece of software) and when i run it in a job, for example, SSIS targets the same data source, but the 64-bit version. I know this can be a work-around but for me it works.